# How do I use guards: parse error on input '|'

Tags: haskell, syntax-error

Edit: This is an old question StackOverflow won't let me delete. At the time I didn't understand when guards were appropriate, and the selected answer gives a good description of that.

I'm trying to write a program in Haskell that takes a list of numbers and returns the value of the largest consecutive subsequence.

I'm getting a compilation error for line 7, the line with the first guard.

```
maxsubseq list = maxsubseqRecurse 0 list

maxsubseqRecurse sofar restOfList =
   if null restOfList
      then sofar
      else
         | if newSofar < 0
         |     then maxsubseqRecurse 0     newRestOfList
         |     else maxsubseqRecurse sofar newRestOfList
         where
            newSofar = sofar + head restOfList
            newRestOfList = tail restOfList
```

Why are the guards not valid syntax? My intention is to make the definition of newSofar and newRestOfList available for the three lines where there are guards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly put, guards are used at the left of `=`, as in

```
f x y
   | cond1 x y = ...
   | cond2 x y = ...
   | otherwise = ...
```

In your code, simply remove the `|` -- you do not need guards. `if` suffices.

Also, using `if null, head, tail` is unidiomatic, since better alternatives exist. Remember that `head,tail` will crash your program the day you will forget about the `null` check. Since pattern matching does not have that issue, it is greatly preferred when possible.

```
maxsubseqRecurse sofar [] = sofar
maxsubseqRecurse sofar (h:newRestOfList) =
    if newSofar < 0
    then maxsubseqRecurse 0     newRestOfList
    else maxsubseqRecurse sofar newRestOfList
       where
       newSofar = sofar + h
```

Reintroducing guards, we obtain:

```
maxsubseqRecurse sofar [] = sofar
maxsubseqRecurse sofar (h:newRestOfList)
   | newSofar < 0 = maxsubseqRecurse 0     newRestOfList
   | otherwise    = maxsubseqRecurse sofar newRestOfList
   where
   newSofar = sofar + h
```